# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException when calculating Salary in Java

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I'm trying to create a program where the user can calculate their daily salary based on when they arrived and left work. I have however received the same error message for the past hour, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at Tidsrapport.main(Time.java:17)
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Time {

        public static void  main(String[] args)
        {
        int hours, minutes, totalhours;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        keyboard.useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");

        System.out.print("When did you arrive at work today [hh:mm]>");
        keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("When did you leave work today [hh:mm]>");
        keyboard.nextInt();

        hours = keyboard.nextInt();
        minutes = keyboard.nextInt();

        totalhours= hours + (minutes/60);
        double salary = totalhours * 9;

        System.out.println("Your salary today is:" + salary + "dollars");

        }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling that exception?

Comment: Hint: some feedback would be welcome; like putting up a comment if things help; or if you got your problem solved; by accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Many a problems:

```
System.out.print("When did you arrive at work today [hh:mm]>");
keyboard.nextInt();
```

An input like 10:15 ... is not an **int**. You have to use

```
next();
```

instead - to return a **String**; and then you have to validate that the incoming string consists of number number colon number number for example.

But of course, **none** of that matters, as you not dong anything with the value provided by the user. You need something like:

```
String rawArrivalTime = keyboard.next();
```

And then you can work with that local variable rawArrivalTime; for validating, parsing, ...

Answer (score 1):

From [the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), the `nextInt()` method will throw these exceptions under these conditions:

InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

Use `hasNextInt()` first to validate if it is really an int.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the other two people kinda answered you, so here are some tips on how to work with error messages:

1. `Exception in thread "main"`, as long you write programs that use one thread, it is always gonna say `in thread "main"`. Simply cause no other threads exsist.
2. `java.util.InputMismatchException` this is one is important, it tells you **why** the program could not continue.
3. The lines starting with `at`. This is the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Basically a list of functions that are currently being invoked (currently = when it crashed).
   So if you see that you're current function is actually correct, but gets bad arguments. Then you use this to see where did the "bad arguments" come from. So this one is telling **where** the program could not continue.

Hope it helps you with future bugs.